# Database Migration - UTC conversion script that can be run multiple times

Tags: t-sql, migration

I'm writing a script that converts a datetime column from server time to UTC time.  I have a function that does this, however, the migration script will be run as part of a larger process with the following constraints:

1. The script must be able to run multiple times (i.e. don't convert the column twice)
2. Can't leave temp tables or other data around after the migration

This is the script so far:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE SOME_TABLE
SET LastModified = [dbo].[f_ServerToUTC]( LastModified )

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Since the milliseconds are not important in my scenario, I've considered setting the millisecond portion to some specific value, indicating that the migration has already been performed.  However, I feel like the probability of encountering this value in unconverted data is too high (given enough).

Is there some other way I can signify that the script has been run, given my constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we solved this is somewhat particular to our system, but may be useful to others.  We have a User-Defined Type, `UtcDateTime`, defined as:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UtcDateTime] FROM [datetime] NOT NULL
```

Since we're updating the column to be UTC instead of server time, it made sense to change the data type as well.  Therefore, we could check to see if the data type had already been changed on the column as a guard against running the conversion more than once.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c
        ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types ty
        ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
    WHERE t.object_id = object_id( 'SOME_TABLE' )
        AND c.name = 'LastModified'
        AND ty.name = 'utcdatetime'
)
BEGIN

    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    ALTER TABLE SOME_TABLE
        ALTER COLUMN [LastModified] UTCDATETIME

    UPDATE SOME_TABLE
    SET LastModified = [dbo].[f_ServerToUTC]( LastModified )

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END
```

Comment: Clever use of types there :) May I ask why it is that your script needed to be rerunnable if you're updating all the data in your column in one UPDATE? Is it down to your deployment process/tool?

Comment: @Danere - Yes, it's because of our deployment process.  It removes a lot of deployment complexity if we make our scripts re-runnable.  This was an exceptional case, normally it's just a simple "if exists, drop X".